# I am trying to execute the unix command from Django API python, but getting below Error: after installing Java

Tags: java, django, unix, path

checked the installed java version :
root@dev# cd /usr/lib/jvm
root@dev:/usr/lib/jvm# ls
default-java  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64

```
UnixCommand= 'java  -cp dataflow-bundled-2.3.0.jar MsSqlMigrator runner=DataflowRunner'
command= UnixCommand
```

I have tried to execute either ways :

1)

```
import os
process=os.system(command)
```

2)

```
process= subprocess.Popen(command)
process = subprocess.Popen(
    command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True
)
output = process.communicate()
print(process)
```

But showing error: 
***sh: 1: API/java: not found
32512
Internal Server Error***

Since I have tried to execute the same command directly in the Unix shell , it's working fine and I have set the Path in ***/etc/environment*** file as well, like `which java` yields **/usr/bin/java**

update in **$JAVA_HOME** and added the same in **$PATH** like `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME`, still showing the same error.

```
UnixCommand= 'java  -cp dataflow-bundled-2.3.0.jar MsSqlMigrator runner=DataflowRunner'
command= UnixCommand
```

I have tried to execute either ways :

1)

```
import os
process=os.system(command)
```

2)

```
process= subprocess.Popen(command)
process = subprocess.Popen(
    command, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True
)
output = process.communicate()
print(process)
```

Expected: executing the unix command through Django API code.

Comment: does it works in terminal using command line

Comment: Put your java command in a shell script and try to execute the script through Python. To debug, add 'echo' in the script to check that PATH and JAVA_HOME are set properly.

Comment: @grey: yes it's working using command line